# Windows 10: How to safely eliminate services and speed up my machine ?

Tags: windows-10

Just installed windows 10 onto a HP Envey tablet. It only has an Atom 2760 CPU (1.8ghz) Now it runs slow as a dog. It wasn't that great on Win8 either.

I look into the Services and there are a large number set to Automatic.

The tablet is used 95% for browsing, and 5% LibreOffice with the ability to print off both.

I could go through the services one by one and shut them off, but there are A LOT I don't want to break anything.

Question: What can I safely do to strip it down to the lightest form I can get without compromising the required functionality ?

Comment: what is slow? Boot, app starts?

Comment: very slow usage, ie browsing even just opening control panel

Comment: follow this: http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3 capture the slowness and share the file. I'll look what is slow.

Answer (score 2):

**Backup**
You start with a full backup clone image of the system before changing anything. Disk clone, or system clone.  It is better to store you user data on a "data disk" and have your OS be on a smaller seperate partition.
I can guarentee that the first few times you start disabling things, your going to wish you could return it all back the way it was once, to try it again from scratch.
The backup is also nesssiary if anything else occurs that has nothing to do with the disabling, retracting the system back the way it was fully , is the only "control" you have for your experiments. The only way you will know it was not something you did.

System restore is not a backup in this case, and microsofts backup methods are not assurance because your backup methods should be operated outside the system, so the restore of the system is then the same.  When the system is screwed up, being able to apply the exact same method to restore as you did to backup, goes like a dream and your back running again.

Registry backup only is an ok backup, it is again not enough, when any file changes (updates) either correlate with changes in the regitry, or things start to crash.

Once you fully have the system backed up, and know you can as easily restore it, nothing is stopping you from being bold and brutal to it.

**Turn It Off**
Before disabling services, if there is anything you wish to "turn on or Turn Off" windows features http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7247-windows-features-turn-off-windows-10-a.html, to remove things, a very few services can be tied to those OS feature programs, and may also "turn off" as you remove them.

**UnInstall**
Any programs you never wanted to use but installed (some have services) should be removed by uninstalling first, it is no use to play disabling games with other program services, if you dont need any of it.

**Disable**
You go to BV http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-10-service-configurations/ Services Configurations  and spend hours breaking the system and learning what kills what, what is interdependant on what, and how many errors you get for touching it.

A few weeks later your an expert, and a new update comes in and it breaks, or something turns itself on when you re-boot, or troubleshooting doesnt work the way it should.  You add a program that had a dependancy, or start up a task that has a dependancy, and you had to know a little about what is what before.
 Is it worth it? yes, is it fraught with possible problems Yes.

Learning to use AutoRuns can help store compare and return but I do not know if autoruns works fully with 10.

What disabling services does not do:
Except for some services that will be either slow now or slow later (indexing, superfetch, ready stuff etc) Most services are not working the cpu, they are just sitting there ready to work only when actually used or needed.  For the most part it is incorrect to say they are "slowing down your cpu".  It does not prevent a virus or malware from re-enabling them, or putting in thier own services.

What disabling services does do:
It can free up some ram for other uses. It can disable some features that could have exploits.  It can disable things that, have been/will be patched about 300 times through all the years of these operating systems. It can disable things that GPO might have been used to disable the same things (which is supposed to be more proper).   It can easily stop your computer from being sharable, it can be used to disable remote accesses. You can even disable the ability for it to net connect the many different ways it can do that.

There are many thing you could also disable that would make situations worse. updates, Scans , certs, firewall, various security things that could keep you out of your own computer, or keep certian software from running.
There are a few services that will completely ruin the bootablility or log-in of the computer.

Some things disabled instead of improve it, will cripple the whole computer (cpu), because the rest of the stuff does not stop Trying to talk to it or work with it. **Change things slowly and test a lot**.  One disable a day :-)

Only making the ram footprint smaller , and stopping things you do not want in the first place, will "improve the performace" any measurable ammount.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for your detailed response !  It sounds to me like this is one big headache which could cost me a mountain of time and even more frustration ! Maybe it's just not worth it.

Many thanks !

Comment: Safe,& in control, thats the way it works here,  the beauty of the great backup is an impervious system, the beauty of the disable is less stuff going on to see what really is happening behind the scenes.